# How to convert Gradle Groovy method in root build.gradle to Gradle Kotlin DSL function in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

In Gradle Groovy root `build.gradle` I have some method defined. For example:

```
File[] getFiles(String path) {
    // do some filtering here and return result array
    return result
}
```

In module `build.gradle` I have some task defined which calls method above. For example:

```
tasks.register("copyFiles") {
    doLast {
        for (String path : pathList) {
            File[] files = getFiles(path)
            // do something with returned files
        }
    }
}
```

In Groovy it is all right. Now I am converting **only** root `build.gradle` to Kotlin DSL `build.gradle.kts`.

I have tried some attempts with setting lambda to extra properties, but without success. They usually fails with exception:

```
Could not find method getFiles() for arguments ...
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
val copyFile by creating(Copy::class) 
{
        into(project.directory)
        into("path") {
            from(bootJar.get().archiveFile.get())

        } 
}
```

This will copy your file onto multiple locations mentioned with into()